# extracting multiple segments from a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I have 3 vectors, `dates`, `fromDates`, and `toDates`.
How can I extract the dates that are between `fromDates[1]` and `toDates[1]`, `fromDates[2]` and `toDates[2]`, etc.

Here's an example. I tried to use dates[between(dates,fromDates,toDates)] but the result is incorrect and there are some warnings.

```
> dates=seq(Sys.Date(),length=1499,by="-1 day")
> head(dates)
[1] "2015-09-04" "2015-09-03" "2015-09-02" "2015-09-01" "2015-08-31" "2015-08-30"
> toDates=seq(Sys.Date()-as.integer(runif(1)*365),length=3,by="-1 year")
> toDates
[1] "2015-08-13" "2014-08-13" "2013-08-13"
> fromDates=toDates-3
> fromDates
[1] "2015-08-10" "2014-08-10" "2013-08-10"
> dates[between(dates,fromDates,toDates)]
[1] "2015-08-11" "2014-08-12" "2013-08-13" "2013-08-10"
Warning messages:
1: In `>=.default`(x, lower) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `<=.default`(x, upper) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

How can I extract the segments without using a loop? Solution where `fromDates` and `toDates` are not vectors but some other simple structures would also be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see how to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: In which package is `between` function included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much clear what you are asking, but I'd try something like the following with your example:

```
dates[(
    findInterval(dates,c(rbind(rev(fromDates),rev(toDates))))
    %% 2) ==1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved my problem.